# How to render tags as raw string in underscore?

Tags: templates, underscore.js

Give the default underscore [template setup](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1400), how could I render out the "<%", "<%=" as raw string?

I know I could change the syntax to those tags to "{{", "{=", but I need to face the same problem to write these tags as raw string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not exactly pretty but you can do it like this:

```
var tmpl = _.template('Underscore: <%= underscore %>, Mustache: {{ {=');
console.log(tmpl({underscore: "<% <%="}));
```

Output is:

```
Underscore: <% <%=, Mustache: {{ {=
```